# Python IDLE 3.3.2 "expected an indent block" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, block, python-idle, indentation

## My first Python code.

So, I just started coding about 45 minutes ago, and after trying to resolve this issue myself I decided to ask for some help. Please feel free to leave some constructive criticism about weather my code is sloppy, erratic, etc. I'm much better a Lua than I am at Python. The issue I've been having in the IDLE Python GUI is that when I hit F5 to run it in the Python Shell, It gives me an error saying "expected an indent block", but doesn't tell me where to place the indent block(s). I thought to start with something simple so I went with coding a working "Age calculator", Here's the code:

```
# Importing necessary modules #

import time
import math

# Start Application #

print ("The age calculator!")
time.sleep(1)
print ("May I collect some information about you?")
yn = (input("Yes or No: "))

# if-elif Based Decisions #

if yn != Yes or No:
    ynInvalid()

elif yn == No:
    exit()

elif yn == Yes:
    ynYes()

elif yn != Yes or No:
    ynInvalid()

#Defining Functions#

def PrintInfo():
    print ("Hello", name, "Nice to meet you!")

def AgeCheck():
    if age <= 0:
    print("Invalid Age!")
    elif age > 0:
    days = age * 365
    minutes = age * 525948
    seconds = age *  31556926
    print("Doing some math please wait...")
    time.sleep(4)
    print(name,"you been alive for", days,"days", minutes, "minutes and", seconds, "seconds, Wow you're really old!")

def ynYes():

    time.sleep(2)
    print (" Please enter your name below.")
    time.sleep(1)
    name = input("Name: ")
    time.sleep(1)
    PrintInfo()
    age = int(input("Age: "))
    AgeCheck()

def ynYesRetry():

    age = int(input("Age: "))
    AgeCheck()

def ynInvalid():
    print("Invalid Argument! Please try Again!")
    ynYesRetry()
```

Comment: As a side note: `if yn != Yes or No:` does not mean what you think it means. First, `Yes` isn't a valid value, and neither is `No`. You probably wanted the strings `'Yes'` and `'No'`. And, once you fix that, `yn != 'Yes' or 'No'` is asking whether `yn` is equal to the value `'Yes' or 'No'`, which is the same as `'Yes'`. And even if you got that right, _every_ value is either not 'Yes' or not 'No', right? What you probably wanted was either `if yn != 'Yes' and yn != 'No'` or `if yn not in ('Yes', 'No')`.

Comment: Another problem is that you're not passing your variables around. Writing `age = int(input("Age: "))` just creates a local variable, within that function. Code in the `AgeCheck` function can't access that variable. What you need to do is pass it as an argument. Do `def AgeCheck(age):`, and then call it as `AgeCheck(age)`.

Answer (score 0):

IDLE never just gives you an error without showing you where the error occurred. If you post the complete traceback, people can figure out what it means, explain it to you, and hopefully explain how you can do it yourself next time.

Also, copying and pasting the actual error, instead of paraphrasing it, makes it much easier for people to debug your problem.

In this case, it's pretty obvious from a quick glance where you've got at least one indentation error:

```
def AgeCheck():
    if age <= 0:
    print("Invalid Age!")
```

The body of an `if` statement has to be indented further than the condition part.

More generally, anything that ends with a `:` is always followed by an indented block.

You may have additional indentation errors; this one may not even be the one that IDLE is telling you about. But hopefully this is enough information to find and fix them all yourself.

Comment: I'm not here to question your knowledge, but IDLE just gave me this:

http://gyazo.com/f1a8eeedb82658c440a3f68e94964441

It starts up the shell as well but as you can see there is no traceback.

Comment: When I do the exact same thing and click OK, it takes me right to the line that's at fault: the `print("Invalid Age!")` line. If you don't show that to people who are trying to help you, we have to guess.

Comment: You're right, normally that's what it does but it doesn't show me what line it's on, I had to get on Notepad+ to see if I could find something wrong. In any case I've fixed the error. I prompted me to Utabify everything and that seemed to have worked.

Comment: If the error popups are not taking you to the error line, something is wrong with your IDLE setup, and you probably want to either fix it, or use a different environment for running Python. (Personally, I find a good programmer's editor and a terminal/DOS window running `ipython` to be a lot more useful than IDLE; if I want an IDE, I need something smarter, like Eclipse PyDev, but I rarely want that. But of course YMMV.)

Answer (score 0):

```
if age <= 0:
print("Invalid Age!")
elif age > 0:
days = age * 365
```

You did not indent this properly.

```
if age <= 0:
    print("Invalid Age!")
elif age > 0:
    days = age * 365
```

Answer (score 0):

AgeCheck should be:

```
def AgeCheck():
    if age <= 0:
        print("Invalid Age!")
    elif age > 0:
        days = age * 365
        minutes = age * 525948
        seconds = age *  31556926
        print("Doing some math please wait...")
        time.sleep(4)
        print(name,"you been alive for", days,"days", minutes, "minutes and", seconds, "seconds, Wow you're really old!")
```

You need to indent after all if and elif statements. That is how Python knows what is included in the statement results.